# Построение колонок не задавая определенное количество

Tags: html, css, css3

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать меню.
Есть меню, в нем может быть разное кол во колонок.
Я пробую делать так https://jsfiddle.net/4nohe9zg/ , но зеленым цветом показан контейнер и он не растягивается под контент, а мне нужно что бы растягивался. Пробовала делать через flex-direction: column;, ситуация такая же

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  columns: 206px auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">  
    <div class="list">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>11</div>
      <div>12</div>
      <div>13</div>
      <div>14</div>
      <div>15</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я изменил высоту у элемента `<div class="wrap"></div>` на 100vh, это означает, что его высота будет равна высоте экрана пользователя, после изменил его ширину (тут как вам нравится, я поставил 300px)

Также изменил элемент `<ul class="wrap"></ul>`, добавив ему `display: flex;` , `flex-direction: column` и `overflow-y: auto` - нужен, чтобы обрезать часть контента, который не совпадает с высотой родителя ([подробнее о overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow))

```
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.list {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужны колонки, то есть `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: мне не нужно, что бы оно скролилось, ширина фиксированного блока 100vw(.wrap), .list не АДАПТИРУЕТСЯ ПОД ШИРИНУ КОЛОНОК - это проблема , flex-direction: row; не подойдет под это.  Может есть какие то другие варианты, но мне в голову ничего пока не приходит вообще, column-fill тоже бесполезен